# How to fetch Map from jmeter global properties in different thread

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter 5.0 where i have piece of java code written inside a JSR223 PostProcessor in a single thread group. The values are getting stored inside the maps and i can view it in the Debug Sampler. The code is as follows -

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

Map gamePlayHistoryMap = new HashMap();
gamePlayHistoryMap.put(vars.get("playerId"), vars.get("GameplayHistoryId"));
props.put("GamePlayHistoryMap", gamePlayHistoryMap);

Map payLevelDetailsMap = new HashMap();
payLevelDetailsMap.put(vars.get("playerId"), vars.get("PayLevelDetails"));
props.put("PayLevelDetailsMap", payLevelDetailsMap);
```

Now i want to access the values of these 2 maps in different thread group. How to do that ? I have tried using JSR223 PreProcessor where i have written code as follows -

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


Map gameTemplateIdMap = props.get("GamePlayHistoryMap");
Map payLevelDetailsMap = props.get("PayLevelDetailsMap");
```

I am unable to get the values as stored in previous thread.Can someone help me in pointing where i might have gone wrong ?

1st Thread Debug Sampler -

> GamePlayHistoryMap={107=3387} HTTPResponse.parsers=htmlParser
>   wmlParser cssParser
>   PayLevelDetailsMap={107={"prizeQuantity":0,"prizeType":{"prizeTypeId":2,"prizeName":"Cash","description":"Promotional
>   Cash","listofErrors":[],"isValid":true},"isValid":true,"description":"$0.3","externalPrizeID":null,"prizeTypeID":2,"gameTemplateID":0,"isNotifySocial":false,"prizeValue":0.3,"payMethodID":1,"winProbability":17.5,"celebrationLevel":null,"payMethod":{"payMethodID":1,"name":"CMS","description":"Account","listofErrors":[],"isValid":true},"listofErrors":[],"payLevelTemplateID":41170,"isNotifySignage":true,"position":3,"celebrationLevelID":1}}

2nd Thread Debug Sampler -

> GamePlayHistoryMap={107=} HTTPResponse.parsers=htmlParser wmlParser
>   cssParser PayLevelDetailsMap={107=}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your 2nd Thread Group is being executed **after** 1st Thread Group? The only failure reason I can think of is that you're trying to read the value from map at the time when it has not yet been defined.

Check out [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) for any suspicious entries. If I'm right and this is the case you can:

1. Tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

   [image]
2. Or use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) in order to block 2nd Thread Group until the value of map is set in the 1st Thread Group

Comment: I already have ticked 'Run Thread Groups consecutively' checkbox and my 2nd Thread Group is executed after the 1st Thread Group. Dnt know why am i not able to fetch the stored values

Comment: Where do i need to fetch the map values ? Is it inside JSR223 PreProcessor ?

Comment: You cannot have single JSR223 PreProcessor, it will not be executed unless you have a Sampler

Comment: Yes i do have a debug sampler in the 2nd thread. Just wondering why would the output of the 1st Thread group debug sampler is showing as intended and nothing on the 2nd ? 'props' should be available globally among all the thread groups.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using the **bsh.shared** property of BeanShell Sampler. 1st Thread group code which populates the map is as follows -

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

Map gamePlayHistoryMap = new HashMap();
Map payLevelDetailsMap = new HashMap();

gamePlayHistoryMap.put(vars.get("playerId"), vars.get("GameplayHistoryId"));
bsh.shared.gphMap = gamePlayHistoryMap;

payLevelDetailsMap.put(vars.get("playerId"), vars.get("PayLevelDetails"));
bsh.shared.pldMap = payLevelDetailsMap;
```

2nd Thread Group code which fetches the map is as follows -

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

Map myMap1 = bsh.shared.gphMap;
vars.put("GamePlayHistoryId", myMap1.get(vars.get("playerId")));
log.info(myMap1.get(vars.get("playerId")));

Map myMap2 = bsh.shared.pldMap;
vars.put("PayLevelDetails", myMap2.get(vars.get("playerId")));
log.info(myMap2.get(vars.get("playerId")));
```

Of course i think this can also be done using JSR223 elements, just need to figure out how. I also need to figure out how to declare the map in the 1st thread group globally so that each time the thread runs the values of the map gets appended. As of now each time the map gets newly initialized whenever the thread runs more than once. Any pointers how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Okay i achieved it by creating another Thread group and initalizing the map once then sharing it via 'bsh.shared' property of BeanShell Sampler as stated above.